# How to add FileSytemObject to my VBA for creating text flat files in Unicode?

Tags: vba, text, unicode, flat-file

I've managed to piece together this VBA which takes data from excel and turns it into .txt flat file. It works exactly as I need, but I would like to alter it so that the end result is saved as Unicode as opposed to ANSI.

I've done some reading and the answer I keep coming back to is to use FileSystemObject. I found a VBA on here that does the job perfectly, but I can't for the life of me work out how to incorporate it into my existing code. Any chance someone could throw me some pointers?

This is my current code:

```
' Defines everything first. So, from B2, across and down.
LastRow = Sheets("Pricing").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = Sheets("Pricing").Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

' File name, path to save to and delimiter.
file = Sheets("Pricing").TextBox1 & ".txt"
If TextBox1.Value = "" Then MsgBox "What we calling it genius?", vbQuestion
If TextBox1.Value = "" Then Exit Sub

Path = "C:\Users\me.me\Desktop\Files\"
Delimeter = "|"

' The magic bit.

    myFileName = Path & file
    FN = FreeFile
    Open myFileName For Output As #FN

    For Row = 2 To LastRow

    For Column = 2 To LastColumn

        If Column = 2 Then Record = Trim(Cells(Row, Column)) Else Record = Record & Delimeter & Trim(Cells(Row, Column))

    Next Column

    Print #FN, Record

    Next Row

    Close #FN

MsgBox "BOOM! LOOKIT ---> " & myFileName

' Opens the finished file.
    
Dim fso As Object
Dim sfile As String
Set fso = CreateObject("shell.application")
sfile = "C:\Users\me.me\Desktop\Files\" & Sheets("Pricing").TextBox1 & ".txt"
fso.Open (sfile)
```

And this is what I've been trying to incorporate (HUGE thanks to [MarkJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15639/markj) for posting this on another question):

```
   Dim fso As Object, MyFile As Object
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set MyFile = fso.CreateTextFile("c:\testfile.txt", False,True) 'Unicode=True'
   MyFile.WriteLine("This is a test.")
   MyFile.Close
```

I just can't get it to work.

Comment: So, do you need to save an Excel sheet content as text file, each cell separated by "|", saved as Unicode. Is this understanding correct? Can you share such a sample workbook you try processing? I would like to test an idea I have in mind...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test the next code. You did not answer my clarification question, but it works using the above comment assumptions. It take the file name, from an `activeX` text box situated on the sheet to be processed. The code should be faster than yours for big ranges, avoiding to iterate between all cells:

```
Sub SaveAsUnicode()
  Dim shP As Worksheet, iRow As Long, Record As String, Delimeter As String
  Dim file As String, myFileName As String, path As String, txtB As MSForms.TextBox
  Dim rng As Range, lastCell As Range, arr, arrRow
  Dim fso As Object, MyFile As Object, shApp As Object
  
  Set shP = Worksheets("Pricinig")
  Set txtB = shP.OLEObjects("TextBox1").Object 'it sets an activeX sheet text box
  file = txtB.Text & ".txt"
  If txtB.value = "" Then MsgBox "What we calling it genius?", vbQuestion: Exit Sub
  
  Set lastCell = shP.cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell) 'last cell of the sheet
  Set rng = shP.Range("A2", lastCell)                       'create the range to be processed
  arr = rng.value                                           'put the range in an array
  
  path = "C:\Users\me.me\Desktop\Files\" 'take care to adjust the path!
  myFileName = path & file
  Delimeter = "|"
    
  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set MyFile = fso.CreateTextFile(myFileName, False, True) 'open the file to write Unicode:
        For iRow = 1 To UBound(arr)                  'itereate between the array rows
            arrRow = Application.Index(arr, iRow, 0) 'make a slice of the currrent arrray row
            Record = Join(arrRow, Delimeter)         'join the iD obtained array, using the set Delimiter
            MyFile.WriteLine (Record)                'write the row in the Unicode file
        Next iRow
  MyFile.Close                                       'close the file
    
 'open the obtained Unicode file:
 Set shApp = CreateObject("shell.application")
 shApp.Open (myFileName)
End Sub
```

I tested the above code on a sheet using characters not supported in ANSI and it works as expected.

Please, send some feedback after testing it, or if my assumptions after reading your question are not correct...

Comment: Thanks FaneDuru. Your understanding is correct. I've tested your code with a small number of records and it works, which is brilliant, but when I try using it with regular volumes, ~25K, it puts excel into not responding for so long that it needs to be closed. My current script executes for the same volume in < 5 seconds. Would there be a way to include the unicode element of yours into mine? That's the piece of the puzzle that I'm struggling with.

Comment: @Jim Can you estimate the maximum number of characters on a row of your workbook? If not something confidential, can you share the workbook in discussion? If yes, you can send it to my personal mail account (see it in my profile).

Comment: @FanDuru, the volumes vary, anything from a few dozen to to tens, to hundreds of thousands, and even millions on occasion. And it's all sensitive information for work, so I'm afraid I am unable to share it. However, I have managed to work out how to incorporate the two codes successfully today and it works a treat now. Thank you so much for your help with pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @Jim Can Glad I could help, anyhow... Can you share the code 'mixture'? I would like to understand where the above code has a weakness. Theoretically, it should be very fast...

Answer (score 0):

@FaneDuru, this is what I ended up putting together, it's working great for me. Thanks again for all of your help.

```
Private Sub FlatButton_Click()

'Does all the setup stuff.
Dim fso As Object, MyFile As Object
Dim MyFileName As String
Dim txtB As MSForms.TextBox

Set shP = Worksheets("Pricing")
Set txtB = shP.OLEObjects("TextBox1").Object
file = txtB.Text & ".txt"
If txtB.Value = "" Then MsgBox "What we calling it?", vbQuestion: Exit Sub

' Defines the range. So, from B2, across and down.
LastRow = Sheets("Pricing").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = Sheets("Pricing").Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'File details.
path = "C:\Users\me.me\Blah\Blah\"
MyFileName = path & file
Delimeter = "|"

' The magic bit.
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set MyFile = fso.CreateTextFile(MyFileName, False, True) '<==== This defines the Unicode bit.
    For Row = 2 To LastRow
    For Column = 2 To LastColumn
        If Column = 2 Then Record = Trim(Cells(Row, Column)) Else Record = Record & Delimeter & Trim(Cells(Row, Column))
    Next Column
    MyFile.WriteLine (Record)
    Next Row
MyFile.Close

MsgBox "BOOM! ---> " & MyFileName

'Option to open the finished product.
If ActiveSheet.CheckBox2.Value = True Then
Set shApp = CreateObject("shell.application")
shApp.Open (MyFileName)
End If

End Sub
```